# Deploy a WPF application with .NET 3/3.5 in a single executable

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, deployment

I have developed a WPF application and the customer is planning to deploy the application on DVDs.

My application is really simple and doesn't require any setup process, but I need to assure that if the client doesn't have .NET 3 installed that it will be installed locally (from the DVD) before starting the WPF application.

So, what's the easiest was to add the .NET 3/3.5 package locally on my DVD and assure it'll be installed before running my application? Remeber that my application will be a standalone application.

Comment: use the cllick once installer. even though they only need the one file it will check for dependancies that you can configure

Comment: @RadioSpace: Work that up into a full answer?

Comment: @NathanTuggy sure, why not.

Comment: @NathanTuggy never hit post last night LOL

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using **Visual Studio Setup Project** for creating a setup package which would check for prerequisites and provide fundamental features like file system, registries, scripting. It is very easy to get started with. Take a look here for a [brief **walkthrough**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/307353/).

Answer (score 0):

when you use the publish option... [image]

The Project Properties has a place to specify the dependancies that will need to be downloaded

[image]

then you simply check the boxes
[image]

there are other more complex ways to go abaout this but for .net 3.5 you don't have to go far